# Is there a maximum value for the ICS, ICAL, Calendar SEQUENCE parameter

Tags: google-calendar, apple-ical, outlook.com-calendar

I have looked for an answer in various specs and can find only "minimum of 0" and "it must be an integer". It seems to fail at different values in different calendars. What would be really useful is if someone knows which calendar has the lowest maximum.

Answer (score 1):

While not having tested against mainstream or others web calendars, the RFC specifies integers to be either positive or negative and RFC5545 section 3.3.8. Integer specifies:

> The valid range
>         for "integer" is -2147483648 to 2147483647.  If the sign is not
>         specified, then the value is assumed to be positive.

Comment: Thanks, I did not come across +/- in the specs, only must be positive or zero. Unix timestamps fail in some calendars, current time is about 2/3 of the maximum for a 32bit integer. I have a feeling some calendars use 16bit integers. Standard specs must be very popular - everyone has their own.